# Mongodb $unionWith, how to choose a specific document

Tags: mongodb

I have 2 collections:

1. userMaster as {userName: 'xxxx', roleId: 1, fullName: 'xxxxxxx'}
2. customerMaster as {userName: 'xxxx', address: 'YYYY', firstName: 'zzzzz', lastName: 'ppppp'}

Now I want to do mongodb $unionWith on userMaster to combine results of two and find users from the given userList, so my aggregation pipeline is like:

```
[
    {'$match': {'userName': {'$in': userList}}
    }, {
      '$unionWith': {
        'coll': 'customerMaster', 
        'pipeline': [
          {'$match': {'userName': {'$in': userList}}
          }
        ]
      }
    }
]
```

Now it is possible that same userName exists in both collections. So to avoid duplicates, I want to add $group to this pipeline. However I want to prefer to customerMaster if it exists there and userMaster otherwise. Because I want the address to come if available.
How to write such $group stage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use a field that only one of the collections have, and sort by it:

```
db.userMaster.aggregate([
  {$match: {userName: {$in: userList}}},
  {$unionWith: {
      coll: "customerMaster",
      pipeline: [{$match: {userName: {$in: userList}}}]
  }},
  {$sort: {roleId: -1}},
  {$group: {_id: "$userName", doc: {$first: "$$ROOT"}}}
])
```

See How it works on the [mongoDB playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8sPHyviHKdz)

Another option in such a case is to use `$lookup` instead of `$unionWith`:

```
db.userMaster.aggregate([
  {$facet: {
      userMaster: [{$match: {userName: {$in: userList}}}],
      customerMaster: [
        {$lookup: {
            from: "customerMaster",
            let: {},
            pipeline: [{$match: {userName: {$in: userList}}}],
            as: "res"
          }}
      ]
  }},
  {$project: {
      userMaster: {$first: "$userMaster"},
      customerMaster: {$first: "$customerMaster"}
  }},
  {$replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {$ifNull: ["$userMaster", {$first: "$customerMaster.res"}]}
  }}
])
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It does solve my problem. However I believe your $lookup solution will be less efficient because as a part of customerMaster in $facet, I am getting each object from userMaster as an array with added element as res from the customerMaster. It won't be a problem here because userList is limited to a few names, but in case userMaster $match results in 1000s documents, it will be a performance hit. Am I correct?

Comment: The `$lookup` solution is for cases of a small `userList` and when `userName` is close to uniqueness. If you have a small `userList`, but  1000s documents are matching it, you will have a logical problem when grouping them, even before the efficiency issue...